# Indexing very large hex file with python

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a program that parses data from a (very) large file that contains even rows of 8 sets of 16 bit hex values. For instance, one row would look like this:

```
edfc b600 edfc 2102 81fb 0000 d1fe 0eff
```

The data files are expected to be anywhere between 1-4 TB, so I wasn't sure what the best approach would be. If I load this file using Python's open() function, could this turn out badly? I'm worried about how much of an impact this will have on my memory if I'm loading such a large file just to index through. Alternatively, if there's a method I can use to load just the section of data I want from the file, that would be ideal, but as far as I know, I don't think that's even possible. Is this correct?

Anyway, Some sort of idea as to how to approach this very general problem would be much appreciated!

Comment: There are certainly generic ways to read certain byte ranges from a file in binary mode, but to be more useful, what is the file *format* that you expect? The hex dump you showed doesn't really establish anything - *any* file contents could be represented in such a way.

Comment: Or are you saying that the file is actually an ascii file containing a hex dump? To get the line that you showed, did you run some kind of hex dump utility, or is this just a simple view of the file contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer from Github. In numpy, there's a function called memmap that works for what I'm doing.

```
samples = np.memmap("hexdump_samples", mode="r", dtype=np.int16)[100:159]
```

This didn't seem to cause any issues with the smaller data set I was using, but I can't imagine this causing any issues with memory with the larger files. As far as I understand, this wouldn't cause any issues.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on your computer hardware, how much RAM you have. Python is an interpreted language with a bunch of safeguards, but I wouldn't risk trying to open that file with Python. I would recommend using C or C++, they are good with large amounts of data and memory management. You can then parse the data in bite sized chunks, maybe 16MB per chunk. Python is a extremely slow and memory inefficient compared to C.